# Checking an object that contains arrays of objects for a value

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, filter

I see this question has been touched on a lot on stack overflow but I can't seem to find one that helps my issue. I have an object that contains many arrays with objects nested inside. I need to find the key of the array that contains the object that a usersID. Ive tried `.filter` and `for in` loops but I keep getting errors.

My data looks like this :

```
{
  FL: [{id: "mp-2d24973e-c610-4b1c-9152...}{id...}],
  TX: [{id: "mp-2d24973e-c610-4b1c-9152...}{id...}],
  LA: [{id: "mp-2d24973e-c610-4b1c-9152...}{id...}],
}
```

Is there a method that allows me to check for a value inside the arrays and if it is found returns the key to that array ie. FL or TX?

```
const practices = data.items
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(practices)){
          console.log(key, value, "KEYVALUE")
          if(value.id === currentUser.currentPracticeID){
            console.log(key)
          }
        }
```

Of course this code doesnt work but this what Ive tried so far. Im still new to dev so any point in the right direction would be great.

Comment: What is `data.items`? Is that the object you showed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `filter()` inside of a `for...in` loop would do it. After looking at the other answers, I should say this will return the first matching ID, rather than an array of all matching ID's like @Barmars answer

```js
const practices = {
  FL: [{id: "mp-2d24973e-c610-4b1c-9152"},{id:"3"}],
  TX: [{id: "mp-2d24973e-c610-4b1c-9153"},{id:"4"}],
  LA: [{id: "mp-2d24973e-c610-4b1c-9154"},{id:"5"}],
}

const findUserKey = (u) => {
  for (const key in practices) {
    if (practices[key].filter(mp => mp.id === u.currentPracticeID).length>0) return key
  }
  return false;
}

let currentUser = {currentPracticeID: "mp-2d24973e-c610-4b1c-9154"}
let check_mp = findUserKey(currentUser)
console.log(check_mp)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object#keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the list of object keys, [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to iterate over this list, and [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to check if the array at each iteration has the `userId` you're searching for:

```js
const getKeyOfUserId = (obj = {}, userId) => 
  Object.keys(obj).find(key =>
    obj[key].findIndex(({ id }) => id === userId) >= 0
  );
  
const obj = {
  FL: [{id: "mp-2d24973e-c610-4b1c-9152"},{id:"mp-2d24973e-c610-4b1c-9153"}],
  TX: [{id: "mp-2d24973e-c610-4b1c-9154"},{id:"mp-2d24973e-c610-4b1c-9155"}],
  LA: [{id: "mp-2d24973e-c610-4b1c-9156"},{id:"mp-2d24973e-c610-4b1c-9157"}]
};
console.log( getKeyOfUserId(obj, "mp-2d24973e-c610-4b1c-9156") );
```

Answer (score 1):

`filter()` is an array method, `practices` is an object. You need to use `Object.entries()` to get an array of keys and values.

Then you can use `.some()` to test if any of the objects in the nested array contain the ID you're looking for.

```js
const practices = {
  FL: [{
    id: "mp-2d24973e-c610-4b1c-9152"
  }, {
    id: "mp-2d24973e-c610-4b1c-9153"
  }],
  TX: [{
    id: "mp-2d24973e-c610-4b1c-9154"
  }, {
    id: "mp-2d24973e-c610-4b1c-9155"
  }],
  LA: [{
    id: "mp-2d24973e-c610-4b1c-9156"
  }, {
    id: "mp-2d24973e-c610-4b1c-9157"
  }]
};

let currentPracticeID = "mp-2d24973e-c610-4b1c-9156";
const states = Object.entries(practices).filter(([key, arr]) => arr.some(({
  id
}) => id == currentPracticeID)).map(([key, arr]) => key);

console.log(states);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```js
const data = {
    FL: [{id: 'ab'}, {id: 'cd'}, {id: 'ef'}],
    TX: [{id: 'hi'}, {id: 'jk'}, {id: 'lm'}],
    LA: [{id: 'no'}, {id: 'pq'}, {id: 'rs'}]
};

const findKey = (id) => {
    let foundKey;
    Object.entries(data).some(([key, objects]) => {
        if (objects.find(object => object.id === id)) {
            foundKey = key;
            return true;
        }            
    });

    return foundKey;
};

console.log(`The data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
console.log(`Looking for object with ID "jk": ${findKey('jk')}`);
```

You loop through the [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of your data, so you have the key and the objects for that key. You simply use [objects.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to see which object matches the ID you're looking for. I would use [array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for this as it stops the loop when you return true, and foundKey will simply be falsy if nothing is found.